# The expression "на душе кошки скребут" without "у кого-н"

Tags: выражения

> Он сегодня весь день не желает вылезать из комнаты. Играет что-то грустное на гитарке и поет. **От** его песни аж **кошки на душе скребут**.

When I see "на душе кошки скребут", I sort of automatically expect the prepositional phrase "у кого-н" to come with it. In this specific instance, however, there is only one prepositional phrase: "от его песни".

How should I interpret the meaning of this structure: "От его песни аж кошки на душе скребут"?

Comment: I would say, ellipsis strikes again: "от его песни [у меня] аж кошки на душе скребут".

Comment: without specific indication i take it to refer to the speaker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the feeling of the speaker, so it can be rewritten as **От его песни у меня аж кошки на душе скребут.** Very often we omit a pronoun when we mean ourselves or it is clear from the context. 
compare:

*He came with his wife.* - **Он пришел с женой.**

*I'll tell my husband.* - **Я скажу мужу.**

*My mother says, that...* - **Мама говорит, что...**

Besides, it can denote a feeling which is generally produced on anybody who hears the song. That means, if you were present there, you would suffer that feeling as well. **[У кого угодно, кто это слышит,] аж кошки на душе скребут.**